# Python class attributes of the same class

Tags: python, class, oop, python-3.7

Can a Python class attribute be of the same type?
Something like:

```
class X:
    def __init__(self, inputStr):
        a = 0
        b = X("Hello")
```

Comment: `b` in your example is not a class attribute, it's just a variable local to the `__init__` function.

Comment: Not like that.  That's an infinite loop, until it exceeds the stack.

Comment: Good point - I think something like this will always end up being an infinite loop - maybe "b" should be made outside the class and then passed to X. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure what is the use case you need it for or whether it was a theoretical question. But you might check out class inheritance if that is what you need.

```
class X:
  def __init__(self, inputStr):
    a = 0
    self.inputStr = inputStr

class Y(X):
  pass
obj = Y('Hello')
print(obj.inputStr)
```

Comment: Not exactly what I am looking for. You can think of my case as a recursive query that ends when a particular condition is met.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. Sorry, I didn't understand the question initially. :)